# HackerRank: XOR-sequence

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

I am trying to solve the [following](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hourrank-5/challenges/xor-se) problem at HackerRank:

> ### XOR-Sequence
>
> An array, \$A\$, is defined as follows:
>
> - \$A_0 = 0\$
> - \$A_x = A_{x-1} \oplus x\$ for \$x>0\$, where \$\oplus\$ is the symbol for XOR
>
> You must answer \$Q\$ questions. Each \$i^{th}\$ question is in the form \$L_i\ R_i\$, and the answer is \$A_{L_i} \oplus A_{L_i+1} \oplus \ldots \oplus A_{R_i-1} \oplus A_{R_i}\$ (the *Xor-Sum* of segment \$[Li,Ri]\$).
>
> Print the answer to each question.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains \$Q\$ (the number of questions).
>   The \$Q\$ subsequent lines each contain two space separated integers, \$L\$ and \$R\$, respectively. Line \$i\$ contains \$L_i\$ and \$R_i\$.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> \$1 \le Q \le 10^5\$
>   \$1 \le L_i \le R_i \le 10^{15}\$

My code is correct, but it's slow. It really starts slowing down once I reach numbers like 269 million for the array index. The max array index can be 10<sup>15</sup>, so it will be really slow. What things can I do to increase the speed?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int N;
  int64_t f_index, l_index;

  std::cin >> N;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    std::cin >> f_index >> l_index;
    int64_t sum = 0;
    int64_t temp;
    for (int64_t index = f_index; index <= l_index; ++index) {
      if (index%4 == 0) {
        temp = sum^index;
        sum = temp;
      } else if (index%4 == 1) {
        temp = sum^1;
        sum = temp;
      } else if (index%4 == 2) {
        temp = sum^(index + 1);
        sum = temp;
      } else if (index%4 == 3) {
        temp = sum^0;
        sum = temp;
      }
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For inputs of size \$10^{15}\$, you are doomed if you use a linear algorithm.  You want to go back to the drawing board and find a more efficient way to do things.  You've worked out a nice pattern for the terms of A_n, now you just need to aggregate them efficiently.  HInt: start by thinking about how you can efficiently compute the XOR sum of [1, (1<<50)-1]?  What about [(1<<50),(1<<50)+(1<<25)+1]?

Comment: Just to elaborate on the comment by @ErickWong: If you can find a pattern that gives you the Xor-Sum of the range [0,N], then you can easily calculate the Xor-Sum of any range as Xor-Sum(0,L−1) ⊕ Xor-Sum(0,R). If you just print out a few terms of the series, you'll discover the pattern soon enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I'll revisit the problem with a fresh insight.

Answer (score 1):

This code is missing a declaration for `int64_t`.  I'm assuming you intended

```
#include <cstdint>
using std::int64_t;
```

That said, I'd skip the `using` and just write the full type name where we need it.

It's not clear why we're using signed types for our arithmetic, nor why we need our values to be *exactly* 64 bits.  I suggest `std::uint_fast16_t` for `N` and `std::uint_fast64_t` for the values.

We're missing the usual check that `>>` was successful before using the values we read.

We have an unnecessary flush after each write because we're using `std::endl` instead of `'\n'`.

The `temp` variable is unnecessary: `temp = sum ^ x; sum = temp;` can be replaced by `sum ^= x;`.

The chain of `if (index % 4)` tests would be clearer as a switch.

---

These correctness and readability fixes get us to

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using value_t = std::uint_fast64_t;

static auto sum_xor_sequence(value_t left, value_t right)
{
    value_t sum = 0;
    for (value_t i = left;  i <= right;  ++i) {
        switch (i % 4) {
        case 0:
            sum ^= i;
            break;
        case 1:
            sum ^= 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            sum ^= i + 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            // nothing
            break;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```
#if USING_GTEST

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(xorsum, simple)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(sum_xor_sequence(0, 5), 7);
    EXPECT_EQ(sum_xor_sequence(0, 1), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(sum_xor_sequence(2, 5), 6);
}

#else

int main()
{
    using count_t = std::uint_fast16_t;

    count_t N;
    std::cin >> N;
    if (!std::cin) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (count_t i = 0;  i < N;  ++i) {
        value_t l, r;
        std::cin >> l >> r;
        if (!std::cin) {
            return 1;
        }
        std::cout << sum_xor_sequence(l, r) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

---

To improve the performance, we need to get rid of the `for` loop that may execute for up to 10¹⁵ iterations each time.  This should be quite straightforward if we derive a formula for `sum_xor_sequence(0, x)`, since we know that we can use a single ⊕ operation on two of those to get the value for a subrange - as demonstrated in the unit test above: f(a,b)≡ f(0,a-1) ⊕ f(0,b).

The derivation of this should be fairly similar to the process used to determine the values in the `switch` from the series definition.

Comment: I see that we need a type of at least 50 unsigned bits, but no reason to restrict the code to run only on platforms that have an _exactly_ 64-bit type.  Remember that it's only provided if the platform _directly supports_ the type (i.e. without any padding bits).